# Cannot manage to solve $\sum _{i=0}^{h-1}\:2^i\left(h-i\right)$

Tags: calculus, data-structure

$$\sum _{i=0}^{h-1}\:2^i\left(h-i\right)$$
wolfram alpha says that $\sum _{i=0}^{h-1}\:=2^{h+1}-h-2$
Which I have no idea how to get to, because I do not know how to solve $$\sum _{i=0}^{h-1}\:=2^ii$$
I am taking data structures and I tried to find the time coplexity of building a heap... came up with this rough formula, then found online an easier way to compute the time complexity and wondered why my way of thinking did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

take into account the relation
$$
\frac{d}{da}\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}{a^{i}}=\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}{ia^{i-1}}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helped me. It sucks I did not take calculus yet.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem. Came up with the general formula:

Comment: $$\sum _{i=0}^{h-1}\left(a^ii\right)=\frac{a^{h+1}\left(\left(h+1\right)\left(a-1\right)-a\right)+a}{\left(a-1\right)^2}$$

Comment: Seems wrong, I obtain $$\frac{a^h(a h-a-h) +a}{(a-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned in the comment that you didn't take calculus yet. Here's an algebraic way.

Let the sum be denoted as $x$.

So, $$x =\sum_{i=0}^{h-1} 2^ii$$

$ x  = 0\cdot2^0 + 1\cdot2^1+2\cdot2^2+\cdots+ (h-1)\cdot2^{h-1}$

$2x = \cdots\ + 0\cdot2^1+ 1\cdot2^2+2\cdot2^3+\cdots+ (h-1)\cdot2^h$

Subtracting the second eqn. from the first,

$x -2x = 0 + 2^1(1-0) + 2^2(2-1) +2^3(3-2) +\cdots+2^{h-1}\left[(h-1)-(h-2)\right] -2^h(h-1)$

$\Rightarrow -x = \left[2+2^2+\cdots+2^{h-1}\right]-2^h(h-1) = 2\left(\dfrac{2^{h-1}-1}{2-1}\right) - 2^h(h-1)$

$\Rightarrow-x = 2^h-2-2^h(h-1) \Rightarrow \color{red}{x = 2^h(h-2)+2} $

Thus, $$x =\sum_{i=0}^{h-1} 2^ii = 2^h(h-2)+2$$

---

$$\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}2^i(h-i) = h\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}2^i - \sum_{i=0}^{h-1}2^ii = 2\left(\dfrac{2^h-1}{2-1}\right)-\left[2^h(h-2)+2\right] =\color{red}{2^{h+1} - h - 2}$$

---

This can be done for any number $a$.

Let,  $x =\sum_{i=0}^{h-1} a^ii$. multiply throughout by $a$ (here multiplied by $2$) and the rest of the process is same.